# Draw a polar plot of gain function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have used MATLAB to draw the following gain function of an antenna array, the code was as follows,

```
Nt=8;
deltat=1;
Lt=8;
omegat=-2:0.01:2;
for j=1:length(omegat)
gainfunction(j)= (1/Nt) * exp(i*pi*deltat* omegat(j)* (Nt-1)) * (sin(pi*Lt*omegat(j))/sin(pi*Lt*omegat(j)*Nt^-1));
end  
plot(omegat,abs(gainfunction))
title( 'Radiation Pattern Cartesian Plot','linewidth',30)
grid on
ylabel('|f(\Omega_r)|','linewidth',25)
xlabel('\Omega_r','linewidth',15)
```

The image below is a radiation pattern of an antenna, i.e it shows the gain function denoted by |f(\Omega)| as function of $\Omega$ from -2 to 2.

My question is I would like to plot the following in **polar coordinates** to see how the main lobe is in degrees.

Any thoughts on how I can continue to the polar plot using MATLAB ?

[image: radiation pattern]

Comment: I replaced v with 'omegat' in your call to plot so that it works is that ok?

Comment: thats right that was my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`polar (omegat*pi/2, abs(gainfunction));`

I scaled omegat by pi/2 because I'm not sure what your convention here is. I'm assuming omegat must range from -pi to +pi and hence, I've scaled it by pi/2. Modify the scaling as you see fit.

Also, don't use `i` or `j` as loop counters in matlab. They're used in many places as iota or the sq root of minus one.

Comment: Thank you very much, actually it is between -2 and 2. I don't know if you know a little about radiation pattern but this is a plot between $cos(theta_1)-cos(theta_2)$. What do you think can we scale it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't remember much about radiation patterns at the moment.`polar()` requires the first argument to be in radians.